# collision detection at the snakegame

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I tried to make my own snake game and I'm stuck at the collision checking.
I can't find out what's wrong with my code:

```
function eatApple() {
        if((x == xx) && (y == yy)) {
        clearApple();
        drawApple();
        sw++;
        sh++;
        score ++;
        score();
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

here is my function for detecting the collision with the apple. x,y are the cordinates for the snake and xx,yy for the apple. sw= snake width and sh= snake height. I've called the function in my newGame function (that contains nearly all my game functions) and it is not working at all...what should I do?

Comment: What you should do is elaborate on "it doesn't work" and show a working example (working in the sense of executable and showing the problem), maybe in the form of a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com).

Comment: First of all, the logic of both snake's width and height increment is wrong. Secondly i dont know how it paints the snake when you change the width but it should add the extra width to the end, the head position of the snake should remain at its position. But since you mentioned this doesnt work at all, we need some extra codes.

Answer (score 0):

Like @IngoBürk said, this is not enough information to solve your problem.
The function does what you expect it to. If the snake's x, y is the same as the apple's xx, yy it will go into the functions clearApple, drawApple and score, as well as update the sw, sh, score variables and then return true.
What goes wrong is outside this function. Your logic regarding the height and width of the snake seems a bit off. Perhaps you should store it in an array like so:

```
snake = [{x:0, y:1}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:2, y:1}, {x:2, y:2}]
```

where snake[0] could represent it's head,and then each time the snakes eat an apple you push another x,y coordinate into the snake?